# VIM: Change cursor to underscore in normal mode

Tags: vim

One nice feature of Sublime Text's Vintage Mode is that entering normal mode makes an underscore under the character you are one, rather than the standard cursor that highlights the current character with a certain background color.

Is there a way in *GUI VIM* to change the normal mode cursor to an underscore under the current character you're on like Sublime Text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. Take a look in [`:h guicursor`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27guicursor%27). Here's my suggestion, trying to keep it as close as the default configuration for the syntax group.

```
:set guicursor+=n:hor20-Cursor/lCursor
```

Comment: Great solution. `hor10` works best for me. I find this one is more practical (will add the blink options, though).

Answer (score 4):

Option `'guicursor'` controls how cursor is displayed.

I've never seen Sublime Text, but line below changes the cursor to underscore on normal mode:

```
 set guicursor=n-ci:hor30-iCursor-blinkwait300-blinkon200-blinkoff150
```

See `:h guicursor` for details on how you can change the cursor.